# PLSQL : Get word between the 3rd # and 4th # in a given machine generated string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have given string that looks like this : 
Given String: `#152#005#001#00000000000000000000#0#   #`
 I would like to extract The numbers between the 3rd and 4th '#', which in this case is 001.

Desired output : `001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(your_string, '^#([^#]+#){2}([^#]+).*$', '\2') AS output
FROM your_table;
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used `^#([^#]+#){2}([^#]+).*$`:

```
^             from the start of the string
#             match an initial #
([^#]+#){2}   followed by two paths (consume 152#005#)
([^#]+)       then match and consume the third term (001)
.*            consume the rest of the string
$             until the end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about such 2 options:

- result_1 uses regular expression's substring (*take the 3rd word*)
- result_2 uses traditional `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '#152#005#001#00000000000000000000#0#   #' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) result_1,
  4         --
  5         substr(col, instr(col, '#', 1, 3) + 1,
  6                     instr(col, '#', 1, 4) - instr(col, '#', 1, 3) - 1) result_2
  7  from test;

RES RES
--- ---
001 001

SQL>
```